# css not select the first class between other container

Tags: css, css-selectors

css doesn't select the first class

`:not(:first)` doesn't work because `.callout` is wrapped by other container

```
.callout:not(:first) {
  color: red;
}

<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="flex-fill">
        <div class="callout">
            Text A
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill">
        <div class="callout">
            Text B - only this set color red
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the `.callout` element whose parent is not the `:first-child` of its parent element

```
.flex-fill:not(:first-child) .callout {
   color: red
}
```

Or just revert the logic and target the `:last-child`

```
.flex-fill:last-child .callout {
   color: red
}
```

Or target the `.callout` inside the second parent element, no matter how many `.flex-fill` siblings you have

```
.flex-fill:nth-child(2) .callout {
   color: red
}
```

> [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jvjWBe)

---

Anyway, I don't recommend to use this kind of selectors or to rely on a specific markup structure because this approach can easily cause maintainability problems as the code grows and, if possible, I'd suggest to place instead a specific class for this purpose on the right element.

Comment: thankyou for reply, if many `.flex-fill` so can't use last-child, but any chance i can change to use like this `<div class="d-flex set-color-red">` and not select the first-child `.callout` warped by `flex-fill` ?